# Не создается бд

Tags: android, sqlite

Вроде делаю все правильно,но бд не создается,подскажите где сделал ошибку.

```
public class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "users.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: и где *создание* базы? Его тут нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел ответ в документации!

> Create a helper object to create, open, and/or manage a database. This
>   method always returns very quickly. The database is not actually
>   created or opened until one of getWritableDatabase() or
>   getReadableDatabase() is called.

Answer (score 1):

Создалась база после того как добавил след код

```
private SQLiteDatabase db;

DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
```

Comment: поставьте у своего ответа «галочку», чтобы движок сайта понимал, что на вопрос получен подходящий ответ.

Comment: Через 2 дня только смогу поставить!

Answer (score 0):

Увидел у [Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

```
public class MySQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public static final String TABLE_COMMENTS = "comments";
  public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
  public static final String COLUMN_COMMENT = "comment";

  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "commments.db";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  // Database creation sql statement
  private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table "
      + TABLE_COMMENTS + "(" + COLUMN_ID
      + " integer primary key autoincrement, " + COLUMN_COMMENT
      + " text not null);";

  public MySQLiteHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
    database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
        "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
            + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_COMMENTS);
    onCreate(db);
  }

}
```

У вас не вижу метода `onCreate()`.

Comment: Если я правильно понял то метод onCreate вызывается при создании базы,в котором уже можно создавать таблицы,но создание самой базы происходит в конструкторе,то есть по сути файл базы уже должен быть создан и без метода onCreate,или я ошибаюсь?

Comment: Пусть меня поправят, но мне думается, что вы создали объект БД, и инструкции для действия ей не передали. Т.е. объект в памяти есть. Но какие действия предпринимать, объект не знает.  В данном примере переопределяется метод onCreate, который, должно быть относится к жизненному циклу, но не к каким либо действиям с БД. Т.е. в вашем коде этот метод тоже вызывается, но по умолчанию он пустой ( как я думаю), стало быть, чтобы что то произошло надо его переопределить. Смысл такой же как если бы вы создавали активити

Comment: В общем, я хотел сказать, что нужно переопределить метод onCreate() и в нем создать БД, которую вы инициализируете в конструкторе ( context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION)

Comment: Переопределил метод,всеравно бд не создается!

Comment: Попробуйте прямо как в примере.

Comment: Что то, может быть в логе выводится?

Comment: Странно конечно,даже ваш пример и то не работает.Просматриваю файл БД на телефоне с помощью программы SQlite Editor,чем еще можно просмотреть? Может дело вовсе не в коде?